# Unit test application with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing

I have project, where I'm using SQLite (file name: myDatabase.db).
For example, I have simple class, here is code:

```
public class teacher : Idatabase {
    private cSQLite = new cSQLite();
    private string _name;
    private string _surname;

    public teacher(string name, string surname)
    {
        _name = name;
        _surname = surname;
        AddToDataBase();
    }

    private void AddToDataBase()
    {
        this.cSQLite.Query = "insert into teachers(name, surname) values = ('" + _name + "', '" + _surname + "');";
        this.cSQLite.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Class cSQLite have implement some important class, for example: SQLiteconnection etc.
All is works in my project, but when I want to test in unitTest:

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1//NDbUnit.Core.SqlLite.SqlLiteDbUnitTest
    {
        Exception execute(string name, string surname)
        {
            try
            {
                teacher t = new teacher(name, surname);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
            return null;
        }
        [TestMethod]
        [DeploymentItem("myDatabase.db")] //its file to 
        public void testCon()
        {
            Exception ex = execute("iiiiii", "dudaa");
            Assert.IsNull(ex);            
        }
```

Then I have bad unit test (fail result, but in my app all is ok :( - every works properly). How can I implement good unit test for my app?

**I'm using Nunit and search in internet NDbUnit.SQLite, but I don't know how to implement it.** Somebody would give me a simple way to this app?

Comment: and what error does the test throw?

Comment: how can i read the ex.Message? I'm begginer in this case (today learn it)

Comment: put a debug on the assert.isnull(ex), then from the menu test -> debug  -> tests in current context, or just comment the assert out..

Comment: SQL logic error or missing database

no such table: teachers

Comment: Only a guess from here but make sure myDatabase.db is added to your project and that in the propertites window whenyou select the file in solution explorer that the copy to output property is set to copy always or copy if newer.